# The number of facets of a polyhedron under linear transformation

Tags: discrete-geometry, convex-polytopes, convex-geometry

Consider a (not necessarily bounded) convex polyhedron $P\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ which has $k$  facets.
Let $L:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ be a linear transformation.

**Question1:** Is there a fixed constant $C$ such that the number of facets of $L(P)$ is bounded by $Ck$ ?

**Edit:**

**Question2:** Is there any bound on the number of facets of $L(P)$ in terms of $P$?

**Question3:** Is there any bound on the number of (none geometrical redundant) half-spaces which defined $L(P)$ in terms of $P$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Every bounded convex polyhedron $Q$ with $v$ vertices is an image of a simplex $P$ with $v$ vertices and $v$ facets by a linear transformation. However, $Q$ may have many facets. For example, the cross-polytopes (dual to hypercubes) have $2d$ vertices and $2^d$ facets, one for each orthant, and $2^d$ is not $O(d)$.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any bound on the number of facets of $L(P)$ in terms of $P$?

Comment: @Mahdi: Yes. For example, cyclic polytopes have the most facets as a function of the number of vertices. There are some easy weaker bounds. So, the number of vertices of $P$ gives you a bound on the number of facets of any linear image of $P$.

Comment: But, you claim is not true for an unbounded polyhedron. For example, consider a polyhedron cone.

Comment: @Mahdi: You can use a projective transformation switching the hyperplane at infinity with a hyperplane not intersecting the polyhedron. Are you saying more than that counting the vertices in affine space might miss vertices at infinity?